# How to remove the box and tick marks in pdfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

Suppose I have a simple function that I want to plot in pgfplots.

[image]

The code I used to draw this (preamble removed) was:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[thick, smooth, no markers]
\addplot {x^2+2}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to remove everything surrounding the function.  I tried looking online to see how this would be done (as well as the pgfplots documentation), but wasn't able to make it work.  How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hide axis`

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  hide axis,
  every axis plot/.style={thick, smooth, no markers}
  ]
\addplot {x^2+2}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your fast response!